# c++ - trying to iterate through files in folder and getting a weird error

Tags: c++17

I'm very new to c++ and am getting and error when trying to run this code which iterates through images in a directory and modifies them. This is the function that gets the images and I'm getting an error on this line:

`std::string curr_path(file.path());` (`file` gets underlined)

the error is
"no instance of constructor matches the argument list
argument types are: (const std::filesystem::path)"

Full function below:

```
void GetAllImgInDir(const std::string &directory_path,
                    std::vector<std::string> &PathFrames)
{

    PathFrames.clear();
    for (const auto& file: recursive_directory_iterator(directory_path))
    {
        std::string curr_path(file.path());
        if ((curr_path.substr(curr_path.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "bmp")||
            (curr_path.substr(curr_path.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "jpeg")||
            (curr_path.substr(curr_path.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "jpg")||
            (curr_path.substr(curr_path.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "png"))
        {
           std::string base_filename = curr_path.substr(curr_path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);
           std::cout<<base_filename.c_str()<<std::endl;
           PathFrames.push_back(base_filename);
        }
    }

    std::sort(PathFrames.begin(),PathFrames.end());

}
```

I thought the issue might be to do with the main method's argument so I tried hard coding the input and output folder names - no luck.

Comment: Stop misusing a string to decompose a path. Just use paths decomposing methods. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it this way use:

```
std::string curr_path(file.path().string());
```

although for this specific case *tkausl* is correct and you would benefit from usage of

```
file.path().extension()
```

which immediately gives you the extension which you could compare with yours.

Comment: Please, don't do it this way.